# ¿Cómo imprimir las letras de una cadena de texto en Perl?

Tags: perl

Necesito acceder a la posición de cada letra de una cadena y después imprimirla por consola. Este es el código:

```
my $name = "Hola Mundo";
my $letra = $name[0];
print $letra;
```

Lo ejecuto y no me funciona. ¿Cómo sería la manera correcta de acceder a cada posición de la cadena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mientras aprendes Perl deberías poner al principio del programa estos *pragmas*:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Perl te ayudará cuando vea algo raro o mal escrito. "`warnings`" te sacará advertencias de código extraño que encuentre. "`strict`" te obligará a declarar todas las variables antes de usarlas. Si quieres aún más información de los errores en tu programa, añade `use diagnostics;`

En cuanto a tu problema, debes crear una lista de elementos a partir del valor escalar. Puedes usar la función split() para hacer la partición. Por ejemplo, en forma de línea de comandos:

```
perl -E '$name = "Hola Mundo"; @name = split //, $name; say $name[0]'
```

El truco está en usar un patrón de separación vacío. Tienes más información sobre split(), en tu ordenador, ejecutando el comando **perldoc -f split**

Comment: Ok muchas gracias amigo por la ayuda.

Comment: Me podrías explicar cómo funciona: split // , $name; say $name[0]

Comment: En la documentación de split, pone «Si el PATRÓN coincide con la cadena vacía, la EXPR es dividida en las posiciones coincidentes (entre los caracteres).» Es decir, el patrón vacío coincide con las posiciones que hay entre los caracteres, por lo que split(), efectivamente, va separando los caracteres uno a uno, y se almacenan en el array @name. Luego, se accede al primer elemento del array con $name[0]. Más información en perldoc -f split, y aquí en español: https://metacpan.org/dist/POD2-ES/view/lib/POD2/ES/perlfunc.pod#split-/PATR%C3%93N/,EXPR,L%C3%8DMITE